# problema para comparar duas strings no java

Tags: java

Olá, eu leio um arquivo de texto
    File arquivo = new File("/caminho/historico");

```
        String ler="";
        try{
            String urlF="/caminho/historico";
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(urlF);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String data = null;
            while((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
                ler+=data;
            }
            fileReader.close();
            reader.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            ler="";
        }catch (IOException e){
            ler="";
        }
```

Preciso que as informacoes salvas nao possam ser repetidas, entao para gravar primeiro analiso se ja tem aquela informacao

```
String[] divLer=ler.split("#");

        ler="";

        for(int n=0;n<divLer.length;n++){
            if(divLer[n]!=sala){
                alerta(divLer[n]+" - "+sala);
                if(ler!="") ler+="#";
                ler+=divLer[n];
            }
        }
        if(ler!="") ler+="#"+sala;
        else ler+=sala;
```

So que nessa linha if(divLer[n]!=sala){ << o arquivo sala contem a mesma string que o objeto no array divLer[n], porem ele nao considera as duas variaveis iguais, e por causa disso repete a informacao na hora de gravar o arquivo de texto... alguem sabe o que ta errado?

Comment: Considerou comparar usando o equals?

Comment: Troque para ```if(!divLer[n].equals(sala)){```

Comment: Ah era isso mesmo, esqueço dessa diferença no java... obrigada